# How to use storyboard on target element from another view?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I use storyboard in order to do animation:

```
  <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Animation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="0.3" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Record" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="0.3" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Info" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="info_content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
```

but targets are in another view XAML. I assume I should use ViewModel in order to access them, but I would need some more hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a `UserControl` with `Button`, and tried to `animate` that Button from `MainWindow`.

Problem : You need reference of the Button which you want to animate, so that you can use it for `Storyboard.Target` property. This can be solved using appropriate handler to get it. I did it using Window's `Loaded` event, and using `FindName`() method of `UserControl`.

The FindName() returns the object, which can be exposed using a DP,  or normal property supported by INPC.

This reference is then bound to the `Storyboard.Target` property.

MainWindow :

```
        <Button ...>
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Name="Sb1">
                            <DoubleAnimation To="150.0" 
                                    Duration="0:0:2" 
                                    Storyboard.Target="{Binding TargetBtn, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

Code,

set DataContext for the Window, `this.DataContext = this;`

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // TargetBtn is a DP
     TargetBtn = (Button)UC1.FindName("Btn1");
}
```

You can also use this approach :

[Dynamically changing TargetName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189069(vs.95).aspx#Anchor_2) , here you should change `Target` property instead of `TargetName` property.

Answer (score 1):

It is business of just `View`. All UI actions such as animation, styling should be done by `View`. `ViewModel` should not know about `View`. It is better to create new Style for all `Button` for your application in `App.xaml` file. If you want to use this style for concrete `Button` just use `x:Key` property.

Let me show an example:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="EventTriggerButton" >
        <Style.Triggers>            
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Animation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="0.3" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Record" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="0.3" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Info" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="info_content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>            
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```